# Subset data using a tuple of conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, filtering

I've got an input data frame and a list of tuples. Using the list of tuples that I will use to filter the data frame. The tuple is structured as:

```
    [(column_name1, min_value1, max_value1),(column_name2, min_value2, max_value2),....,(column_namen, min_valuen, max_valuen)]
```

How do I iterate through the list of tuples knowing the max and min condition on the data frame I am given? The column_names given match the columns names in the data frame so there isn't any need to make sure the column exists.

Thanks!

Comment: "How do I iterate through the list of tuples knowing the max and min condition on the data frame" What do you mean? Is that the question? If it is then please explain.

Comment: @Jab *Using the list of tuples that I will use to filter the dataframe*. OP wants to filter results based on a specific column and maybe between the max and min values provided?

Comment: How do you want to filter the data exactly? Do you have some sample input and output?

Comment: Hey everyone, I appreciate the help! I was able to figure out the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) operator:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame([{k: random.randint(0, 100) for k in 'abcde'} for i in range(10)])
df
     a   b   c   d   e
0   35  60  24  13  27
1   86  11  18  60  96
2   61  68  94   9  68
3   67   2  75  47   9
4   79  94   6  60   4
5   50  75  13  67  72
6  100   5  46  46  91
7   11  67  26  44  82
8   89   6   8  53  30
9   71  73  17   5  66


criteria = [('b', 4, 35), ('c', 20, 99)]

for col, _min, _max in criteria:
    # this is a series of type bool you can use
    # to filter your column
    mask = df[col].between(_min, _max)

    # this will get the values from that particular
    # column that satisfy the condition (condition is true)
    df[col][mask]

1    11
6     5
8     6
Name: b, dtype: int64


0    24
2    94
3    75
6    46
7    26
Name: c, dtype: int64
```